# Cannot change R.java in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, r.java-file

I'm using Android Studio and in the `R.java` file in a line

```
public static final int action/map=0x7f090043;
```

giving an error `error: ';' expected` & `error: <identifier> expected`. How to resolve this?

I tried to change `action/map` into `action_map` but since generated file can't be change having problem again.

Comment: It's not recommended to change R class

Comment: @Abdellah yeah I know. But how to resolve the error?

Comment: change your `action/map` id to `action_map` and clean your project

Comment: you can't have slash in your names for resources, pictures etc.
so change the name and then rebuild the project.

Comment: Build -> Clean Project

Comment: Hey did you find solution for this? Am facing same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try a project clean and then a Rebuild.

Build -> Clean Project
then
Build -> Rebuild Project